# sql server .net framework error

Tags: sql-server, clr

i try to install a dll in sql server 2012 but the following error occures:

**Assembly XXX was built using version v1.1.4322 of the .NET Framework. SQL Server currently uses version v4.0.30319.**

this assembly works in sql server 2005.

Comment: SQL Server only ever supported the v2.0 CLR (2005 - 2008 R2) and then, as you've found out, the v4.0 CLR (2012). I don't see how you could have possibly loaded a .NET/CLR 1.x assembly, even with earlier versions of SQL Server - at least in a supported way.

Comment: what about this error: Assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used.